# JavaScript executed only after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a text field to insert user names. I am using JavaScript to detect when the user enters a name and then, combined with a PHP file, to check if the user name already exists on the data base. The page is working as expected, every time the user enters a name, the JavaScript shows at a  position if the name is available or not.

My problem now is that the JavaScript only works after re-loading the page at the browser. The first time the page is loaded, nothing happens when the user enters a name. After reloading the page, it works.

Any help is welcome.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>RestAppXXI</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.ico">
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
//function to check username availability   
function check_availability(){

        //get the username
        var username = $('#username').val();

        //use ajax to run the check
        $.post("check_username.php", { username: username },
            function(result){
                console.log(result);
                //if the result is 1
                if(result == 1){

                    //show that the username is available
                    $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' está disponible');
                }else{

                    //show that the username is NOT available
                    $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' NO está disponible');
                }
        });

}  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">


        <h1>Nuevo Personal</h1>
    </div>
  <div data-role="content">
      <div align="center">
        <p><a href="plogin-sp.html" data-ajax="false"></a><img src="logorestappxxi.jpg" width="75" height="75"></p>



        <p>Bienvenid@ <?php echo 
        $_SESSION[myusername]." / ".$_SESSION[Region]?></p>

      </div>
      <section id="c5">
    <div class="page-header">
            <h1 align="center">Nuevo Personal<?php echo "<span class='label label-important'> $count</span>"; ?></h1>
      </div>
     <div align="center">

        <?php
if ( empty( $_POST ) ){
?>
    </div>
    <form name='registration' data-ajax="false" action='nuevomesero.php' method='POST' />

      <div align="center">Alias: </div>

    <div align="center">
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="aliasq"  id='username'  onkeyup="check_availability()"/><div id='username_availability_result'></div>
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp; </p>
      <div align="center">
        <div align="center">Nombre completo: </div>

    <input type="text" name="nombreq" />
  </div>

    <div align="center">
    <div align="center">Restaurante: </div>
    <td><p>
      <select name="restaurante">
        <?php 
do {  
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id_restaurante']?>" ><?php echo $row_Recordset1['nombre_restaurante']?></option>
        <?php
} while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
?>
      </select>
    </p></td>
    <div align="center">Contraseña: </div>

    <input type="text" name="passq" />
    <button type="submit"  >Añadir el nuevo personal y regresar</button>
      </form>
  <?php
} else {
}


?>
    </div>
  </div>
      </section>
    </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because you did not keep any event attach to the function.
Do you want to call the function before form submit or immedaitely after entering the name

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
//function to check username availability   
function check_availability(){

  $('#username').keyup(function(){
        //get the username
        var username = $('#username').val();

        //use ajax to run the check
        $.post("check_username.php", { username: username },
            function(result){
                console.log(result);
                //if the result is 1
                if(result == 1){

                    //show that the username is available
                    $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' está disponible');
                }else{

                    //show that the username is NOT available
                    $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' NO está disponible');
                }
        });
  });
});

}  
</script>
```

Comment: Add this as a comment dude

Comment: Thank you. I want to call the function immediately after entering the name. This is the function call: onkeyup="check_availability()"

Comment: Can't coz my rep is still less that why

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated my code with yours, but the same issue is happening. The JavaScript is only working after re-loading the page.

Comment: did u remove onkey from the input field in html code

Comment: i forget to add the document.ready  see the above edited code. Hope it works this time

Comment: No, but I have removed it now, and at this point, the JavaScript is not called, neither after re-loading the page.

Comment: @Don, adding your proposal is not working in any case, neither after reloading the page.

Comment: one last try since we are adding the event already in the script . We don't need the function defination function check_availability() . Simple write the body of the function is more than enough

Comment: mayb cos u dnt include the jquery.min.js file for the jquery to take effect